# Running a react native app on a new computer

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I have been developing a new react-native application. starting from  and so using Expo.

I have the thing in source control and have just opened it on a mac. When I do `npm install` I get the following warns

```
npm WARN react-native-branch@2.0.0-beta.3 requires a peer of react@>=15.4.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN lottie-react-native@1.1.1 requires a peer of react@>=15.3.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-native-maps@0.15.2 requires a peer of react@>=15.4.0 but none was installed
npm WARN react-static-container@1.0.1 requires a peer of react@^0.13.0 || ^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-test-renderer@15.4.2 requires a peer of react@^15.4.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-dom@15.6.1 requires a peer of react@^15.6.1 but none was installed.
```

When I did `npm start` the barcocde was displayed but then the build took 5 minutes and failed to load on the phone (time out).

I made a blank file change to spur a re-build. this happened instantly, but on the phone got errors along the lines off..

```
16:23:59: Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `flex` of type `function` supplied to `View`, expected `number`.
Bad object: {}
```

What thing about package management/react/react-native have I managed to misunderstand? The machine it works on is a PC the non working one is a mac mini.

my package.json is like this.

```
{
  "name": "super-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "jest": "19.0.2",
    "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "~15.4.1",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-native-experimental-navigation": "0.26.x",
    "react-native-tabs": "^1.0.9",
    "react-static-container": "1.0.1",
    "react-native-scripts": "0.0.40",
    "jest-expo": "~18.0.0"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apsl-react-native-button": "^3.0.2",
    "expo": "^18.0.3",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.45.0",
    "react-native-button": "^1.8.2",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.39.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did `brew install yarn` then happy days.

Still feel lost in a web of unknown moving parts in this ecosystem!